# php curl code to skip lines from being scraped

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to scrape a HTML page. It scrapes the data between the pre tags perfectly. I would however like skip the first five lines. Is there anything I can add to the code to do this? Here is my code:

```
<?php

function curl_download($Url){

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('cURL is not installed. Install and try again.');
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
$start = strpos($output, '<pre>');
$end = strpos($output, '</pre>', $start);
$length = $end-$start;
$output = substr($output, $start, $length);    


curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}

print curl_download('http://athleticsnews.co.za/results/20140207BOLALeague3/140207F006.htm');

?>
```

This is what the HTML looks like that gets pulled in:

```
<pre>
AllTrax Timing - Contractor License                     4/22/2014 - 8:31 AM
                Boland Athletics League 3 - 2/7/2014                    
                        Hosted by Maties AC                             
                     Coetzenburg, Stellenbosch                          

Event 6  Girls 14-15 200 Meter Sprint
```

So I am trying to exclude the first four lines plus the blank line and start scraping from the line that starts with Event 6 ...

Comment: Can you not apply a regex on the curl output?

Comment: you can use explode to break the $output and get your desired part

Comment: which five lines you are not getting?

Comment: `explode()` on new-lines and use `array_slice()` to remove the elements you don't need.

Comment: @IamNotaBug I am trying to exclude the first 5 rows

Comment: hey @user3315413 do you have any idea  that first five line , how that could be like? i meant those are static or dynamically changing

Comment: @ I am Not a Bug it is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to break the lines apart and select the lines you want:

```
$str = curl_download('http://.../140207F006.htm');
$re = "/([^\n\r]+)/m"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  AllTrax Timing - Contractor License                     4/22/2014 - 8:31 AM
    [1] =>                     Boland Athletics League 3 - 2/7/2014                    
    [2] =>                             Hosted by Maties AC                             
    [3] =>                          Coetzenburg, Stellenbosch                          
    [4] =>  
    [5] => Event 6  Girls 14-15 200 Meter Sprint
    [6] => ============================================================================
    [7] =>     Name                     Age Team                    Finals  Wind Points
    [8] => ============================================================================
    [9] => Finals                                                                      
    [10] =>   1 Shan Fourie                  Bola                     29.03   NWI  10  
)
```

To print out only the last 5 lines, you can do

```
$matches = $matches[1];
$str = "";
for($i = 5; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $str .= $matches[$i] . PHP_EOL; // Preserve the new line
}
echo $str;
```

Results:

```
Event 6  Girls 14-15 200 Meter Sprint
============================================================================
    Name                     Age Team                    Finals  Wind Points
============================================================================
Finals                                                                      
  1 Shan Fourie                  Bola                     29.03   NWI  10
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/ijPiP6

Comment: The regex works perfectly, but how do I display from [5] to [10]? I am unfamiliar with regex.

Comment: Perfect, but I get everything double. First the output like your first result and then under that like your second result above.

Comment: Remove `print_r($matches[1]);` - that was for a demonstration

Comment: Now it displays only the correct data, but everything is in one line and not in 6 rows underneath each other like yours.

Comment: There is a lot to know about PHP. In this exact case, change PHP_EOL to `"<br>"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78934/discussion-between-user3315413-and-drakes).

Comment: One more question if I may. My version removed the spaces between the words and replaced it with a single space, not like your version that kept the correct spacings. My code looks exactly as that which you suggested except for the PHP_EOL that I replaced with <br>.
Any ideas here?

Comment: Surround the output with `<pre>`  and `</pre>` to keep the spacing. Research this tag. SO automatically puts this tag around code in questions and answers so that is why the spacing is preserved in my answer.